# How to create a multi-level menu schema in Zod

Tags: typescript, zod

I am trying to create a multi-level schema for Zod that can be derived from this data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Devices",
            "items": [
                {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "title": "something",
                            "url": "/products/devices/something"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "something3",
                            "url": "/products/devices/something3"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "something2",
                            "url": "/products/devices/something2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "title": "Flower + Concentrates",
                    "url": "/devices/flower-and-concentrate"
                },
                {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "title": "something",
                            "url": "/products/devices/something"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "something3",
                            "url": "/products/devices/something3"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "something2",
                            "url": "/products/devices/something2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "title": "something",
                    "url": "/devices/something"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "CBD",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "something",
                    "url": "/products/devices/something"
                },
                {
                    "title": "something3",
                    "url": "/products/devices/something3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "something2",
                    "url": "/products/devices/something2"
                }
            ]
        }
  ...
```

So far I have:

```
export const menuItemSchema = z.object({
  url: z.string(),
  title: z.string(),
});

export const menuSchema = z.object({
  url: z.string().optional(),
  title: z.string(),
  items: z.array(menuItemSchema),
});
```

However, I can't figure out how to make `menuSchema` recursive to account for multi-level menus. I've read the documentation and don't see anything about this. For context, I am using a CMS to get this data and Zod to ensure all menus abide by this schema. So it should be able to also work on one-level menus.

EDIT:

I've found a piece of [documentation](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#recursive-types) for recursion, but it seems like I may have messed up somewhere since you can pass in additional keys where I only want `title, items, and url`:

```
const baseMenu = z.object({
  title: z.string().optional(),
  url: z.string().optional(),
});

type Menu = z.infer<typeof baseMenu> & {
  items?: Menu[];
};

const MenuSchema: z.ZodType<Menu> = baseMenu.extend({
  items: z.lazy(() => MenuSchema.array().optional()),
});

console.log(MenuSchema.safeParse({
  data: [
    {
      title: 'Devices',
      items: [
        {
          items: [
            {
              title: 'something',
              url: '/products/devices/something',
            },
            {
              title: 'something3',
              url: '/products/devices/something3',
            },
            {
              title: 'something2',
              url: '/products/devices/something2',
            },
          ],
          title: 'Flower + Concentrates',
          url: '/devices/flower-and-concentrate',
        },
        {
          items: [
            {
              title: 'something',
              url: '/products/devices/something',
            },
            {
              title: 'something3',
              url: '/products/devices/something3',
            },
            {
              title: 'something2',
              url: '/products/devices/something2',
            },
          ],
          title: 'something',
          url: '/devices/something',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'CBD',
      items: [
        {
          title: 'something',
          url: '/products/devices/something',
        },
        {
          title: 'something3',
          url: '/products/devices/something3',
        },
        {
          title: 'something2',
          url: '/products/devices/something2',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the data, I've identified two different types. There is the top level menu item type which doesn't have a URL and then there are menu items which have a `url`, `title`, and optionally a recursive list of menu items. I think the place where you're getting stuck is that the top level menu type feels very similar to the menu items, but I think it's better to consider them two distinct types. With that in mind, you can formulate your schemas as follows:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

// This is a bit upside down, but we specify the recursive inner type
// first because we're going to use it with the top level menu schema later.
interface MenuItem {
  title: string;
  items?: MenuItem[];
  url: string;
}

// Recursive types rely on the type already existing, it can't infer
// what the type should be which is why there is an explicit interface
// definition.
const MenuItemSchema: z.ZodType<MenuItem> = z.lazy(() => z.object({
  title: z.string(),
  // Recursive use of the schema
  items: MenuItemSchema.array().optional(),
  url: z.string(),
}));

// A fully separate type for the outermost menu
const TopLevelMenuSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string(),
  items: MenuItemSchema.array(),
});

type TopLevelMenu = z.infer<typeof TopLevelMenuSchema>;
```

Then you can parse your input data with something like

```js
z.object({ data: TopLevelMenuSchema.array() }).safeParse(data);
```